# how can I access shell command line from telnet?

Tags: shell, telnet

I develop a server code in c to connect remotely over telnet. I want to access the bash cmd of server over telnet. Is there any way or not?
Better question is: Is there any solution to connect remotely via telnet to linux instead of ssh?

Comment: You question is too broad. What research did you do? What have you tried? Do you understand what "telnet" is? You might want to research `xinetd`. And `Is there any way` yes. `Is there any solution` yes, but you'll get no login, it's better to stick to ssh. What _programming_ problem are you struggling with?

Comment: Hello. I have a C code that run on an embedded system which utilize libcli (a free command line interface over telnet). I want to access linux shell command line of linux of embedded system remotely over telnet with a libcli command.

Comment: `I want to` Great then do it. Please read [ask].